# How do you add a generator task to resourceGenerators in a SBT autoplugin?

Tags: sbt

I am writing a `Autoplugin` in SBT. The plugin should generate some files into `resourceManaged`. With the code below (work in progress), I am not seeing the `FOOO` output when I run `compile` but I see it when I invoke the task directly with `yamlGen`, which makes me think that for some reason my task isn't properly added as a resource generator. I checked a bunch of other generator plugins and they pretty much do it like this. Whats the problem here?

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object SamplePlugin extends AutoPlugin {
  override def trigger = allRequirements

  val yamlSourceFolder = SettingKey[File](
    "yaml-source-folder",
    "description"
  )

  val yamlSources = SettingKey[Seq[File]](
    "yaml-sources",
    "description"
  )

  val outputFolder = SettingKey[File](
    "output-folder",
    "description"
  )

  val yamlGen = TaskKey[Seq[File]](
    "yaml-gen",
    "description"
  )

  def yamlSettings(conf: Configuration): Seq[Setting[_]] = inConfig(conf)(Seq(
    yamlSourceFolder <<= (sourceDirectory in Compile) { _ / "yamin" },
    yamlSources <<= yamlSourceFolder { srcDir => (srcDir ** "*.yaml").get },
    outputFolder <<= (resourceManaged in Compile) { _ / "yamout" },
    yamlGen <<= (streams, yamlSources, outputFolder).map {
      (out, sources, outputDir) =>
        println("FOOO")
        // implement me
        (outputDir ** "*.abc").get
    },
    resourceGenerators <+= yamlGen
  ))

  override def projectSettings = yamlSettings(Compile)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer by Mark Harrah on on some other forum

> `compile` doesn't trigger resource generation because it isn't needed for compilation. It will get triggered for `package` or `run` or other tasks that need resources.

However, what confuses me is that you need to add yamlGen in the project directly:

```
   val root = (project in file("."))
       .enablePlugins(SamplePlugin)
       .settings(
          resourceGenerators in Compile <+= yamlGen in Compile
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

With [some help](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sbt-dev/iz68kvnqkVA) from Joshua Suereth I got it working. Was missing the dependency on the `JvmPlugin` which is apperently required so that my generator in `resourceGenerators` doesn't get overwritten. Adding this fixed it:

```
override def requires: Plugins = plugins.JvmPlugin
```